# AutoLISP: Removing consecutive duplicates in list

Tags: lisp, autolisp

I've been looking for an efficient way of removing consecutive duplicates in a list of points.

My original thinking was to loop through the elements of the list making a comparison with the (n-1)th element and removing it if its equal. But then it is not trivial to remove an element in a list and using another function would make it inefficient.

I am aware of Lee Mac's [RemoveOnce](http://www.lee-mac.com/removeonce.html) function but I don't know how to modify it to make a comparison between consecutive elements of a list.

The goal as an example would be the following:

```
List = (p1 p2 p3 p3 p3 p2 p2 p4)

List_without_consecutive_duplicates = (p1 p2 p3 p2 p4)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an iterative method:

```
(defun remcondupes ( l / r )
    (while l
        (if (not (equal (car l) (cadr l) 1e-8))
            (setq r (cons (car l) r))
        )
        (setq l (cdr l))
    )
    (reverse r)
)
```

And here's a recursive method:

```
(defun remcondupes ( l )
    (if l
        (if (equal (car l) (cadr l) 1e-8)
            (remcondupes (cdr l))
            (cons (car l) (remcondupes (cdr l)))
        )
    )
)
```

In both of the above, the first element in the list is compared to the second using the `equal` function with a tolerance of `1e-8` (since we're comparing points), with the first element discarded if this test is validated.

**Testing:**

```
_$ (setq p1 '(1.2 2.3) p2 '(3.4 4.5) p3 '(5.6 6.7) p4 '(7.8 8.9))
(7.8 8.9)
_$ (setq lst (list p1 p2 p3 p3 p3 p2 p2 p4))
((1.2 2.3) (3.4 4.5) (5.6 6.7) (5.6 6.7) (5.6 6.7) (3.4 4.5) (3.4 4.5) (7.8 8.9))
_$ (remcondupes lst)
((1.2 2.3) (3.4 4.5) (5.6 6.7) (3.4 4.5) (7.8 8.9))
```

#### EDIT:

Alternatively, to account for consecutive points each successively within the comparison tolerance (per Will's comments below), you might consider the following variations:

```
(defun remcondupes ( l / r )
    (while l
        (if (equal (car l) (cadr l) 1e-8)
            (setq l (cons (car l) (cddr l)))
            (setq r (cons (car l) r)
                  l (cdr l)
            )
        )
    )
    (reverse r)
)
```

```
(defun remcondupes ( l )
    (if l
        (if (equal (car l) (cadr l) 1e-8)
            (remcondupes (cons (car l) (cddr l)))
            (cons (car l) (remcondupes (cdr  l)))
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: imagine a list of points at 5e-9 distance one from the next.

Comment: @WillNess I take your point and the tolerance could be supplied as an argument if necessary, but in practical terms a tolerance of 1e-8 is adequate for most if not all drawings.

Comment: Thanks @LeeMac! How would you adapt this to remove consecutive duplicate points in a polyline? (with or without Bulges)
Is vla-put-Coordinates enough?

Comment: no, the thing I was pointing out is,  out of say 10,000 points your algorithm would only keep the first. :) the correct one would keep every 2nd, or at the worst every 3rd.

Comment: @WillNess thank you for your observation - I have offered up two possible alternatives to account for this scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Lee Mac . I find it hard to understand the case you make @WillNess. Can you please develop what do you mean by the problem between keeping the first, second or 3rd?

Comment: @user14693180 try the first function in this answer with the tolerance of `1.5` and the list `'((0 0) (0 1) (0 2) (0 3) (0 4) (0 5))`. then try the new version and compare the results.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way which I think is legal AutoLISP:

```
(defun remove-successive-duplicates (l / results current)
  (cond
   ((null l)
    l)
   (t
    (setq current (car l)
          results (list current))
    (foreach e (cdr l)
      (cond
       ((not (eq e current))
        (setq current e
              results (cons e results)))))
    (reverse results))))
```

You can do better than this if there are destructive functions on lists which it looks like there are not, or if there are list filtering functions which it also looks like there are not.

Here is another way which is much prettier but will cause stack overflows with long lists:

```
(defun remove-successive-duplicates (l)
  (cond
   ((or (null l) (null (cdr l)))
    l)
   (t
    (cons (car l) (remove-current-duplicates-loop (cdr l) (car l))))))

(defun remove-successive-duplicates-loop (l current)
  (cond
   ((null (cdr l))
    (cond
     ((eq (car l) current)
      '())
     (t
      l)))
   ((eq (car l) current)
    (remove-successive-duplicates-loop (cdr l) current))
   (t
    (cons (car l) (remove-successive-duplicates-loop (cdr l) (car l))))))
```

Comment: Thanks @tfb! How would you adapt this to remove consecutive duplicate points in a polyline? (with or without Bulges) Would vla-put-Coordinates be enough?

Comment: @user14693180: I can't answer that – not because I don't want to but because I don't really know any AutoCAD.  I suspect the other person who answered may do and their answer is kind of better than mine anyway.  Sorry!